# wxWidgets: Drawing bitmaps tiles into a wxPanel

Tags: c++, bitmap, wxwidgets

So I am trying to draw an arena of sorts with players. I really don't have a clue as to what is happening but I think it has something to do with the speed that the wxMemoryDC draws the bit map.

I am trying to load a whole bunch of bitmap tiles into a panel. Below is the code that does this. Suggestions for a better way would be greatly appreciated. I know that there is a way to do this with wxBufferedDC but I couldn't figure out how to do this properly.

```
void RobotWarsFrame::OnButtonStartClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(PanelArena);

    if (!dc.CanDrawBitmap())
    {
        wxMessageBox(wxT("ERROR"), wxT("Cannot draw bitmaps on panel"),wxICON_ERROR);
        Close();
    }

    for (short int row = 0; row < TOTAL_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (short int column = 0; column < TOTAL_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            wxString path(arena->getCell(row, column)->getContent()->getPathToImage().c_str(), wxConvUTF8);
            wxBitmap image(path, wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP);
            if (!image.Ok())
            {
                wxString error;
                error.Printf(wxT("Image %s did not load"), path.c_str());
                wxMessageBox(error);
                Close();
            }
            dc.DrawBitmap(image, wxCoord(column * BITMAP_DIMENSIONS), wxCoord(row * BITMAP_DIMENSIONS), false);
        }
    }
}
```

The program crashes at different points of the dc.DrawBitmap on each run. If I stop it after each dc.DrawBitmap for about half a second it works.

I'm frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite inefficient as you should really cache the bitmaps instead of loading them from file during every paint (possibly many, many times), but this shouldn't make it crash.

It's hard to know why exactly does it crash because there is nothing obviously wrong in the code you show. You really ought to run your program under debugger and look at the stack trace when it crashes, it will almost certainly have some valuable information.